# @RequestScope vs ThreadLocal for mutlti tenant in Quarkus with Mutiny?

Tags: quarkus, multi-tenant, thread-local, mutiny, requestscope

I have a multitenant Quarkus application. For each process, I need to store context information about the tenant that owns the process. This information is necessary for the HibernateTenantResolver and other multitenant-specific implementations to determine the appropriate context for handling the data.

Currently, I am using a `@RequestScoped` bean to store the tenant information. Whenever I run an asynchronous operation, I ensure that I create a new request scope on the async thread and copy the tenant information.

I initially chose the request scope because all `@RequestScoped` beans are destroyed after the scope ends. This approach eliminates the need to worry about thread reuse and accidentally writing into another tenant's database.

However, implementing this approach requires some tinkering (e.g. a `UniInterceptor`), and I have some doubts.

An alternative idea is to directly use a `ThreadLocal` reference instead of a `@RequestScoped` bean to store the tenant information. I am aware that Smallrye supports thread-local context propagation, which could eliminate the need for tinkering with request scopes.

Nevertheless, I have concerns about setting a `ThreadLocal` reference on a thread that might get reused, potentially leading to accessing the wrong tenant's database.

Are these doubts reasonable? Which approach is better? Should I stick with my `@RequestScoped` approach, or can I reliably solve this using `ThreadLocal`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `@RequestScope` with [Context Propagation](https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation) is the way to go.
Dealing with `ThreadLocal` manually is going to be very error prone.

Comment: I think I've might been able to manage it. I really stuggled with the request scope duration and ended up disabling `quarkus.arc.context-propagation.enabled` and using a `UniInterceptor` to recreate a new request scope when switching onto other (async) threads. I couldn't find much documentation about `quarkus.arc.context-propagation.enabled`.  What exactly is the full impact when disabling it?

Comment: What problems did you have with `@RequestScope`? If `quarkus.arc.context-propagation.enabled=false`, then using request scoped beans in uni chains will not work properly.

Comment: I have processes which I fork of the api request and might run longer as the request scope of the original request is active. By disabling it, I can create a new detached request scope by using a custom `UniInterceptor`, which seems to do the job. I proposed to enhance the documentation about the configuration: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34123#issuecomment-1596840163